# CCSprite to follow random path

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

How would i go about creating a random path and having a sprite follow it?
As soon as it reaches the end of the path to pause and start on a new path, and also to have more than one if i need to ?
I was thinking generate random coordinate onscreen and use CCMoveTo but that would make a straight line and would be boring. I would like to duplicate the behavior of an insect flying around. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

How about this simple recipe: have a persistent velocity vector `float vx, vy;` that you normalize by `sqrtf((vx * vx) + (vy * vy))` before replacing your `CCMoveTo` action to ensure constant speed. Before normalization, however, add small zero-centered random values, e.g. between `-0.3f` and `0.3f` to `vx` and `vy`. Very small ranges for the random value will give you smooth persistent paths, larger ranges will make the path less persistent and jittery like that of an insect. Another option would be to roll the dice another time at each update, and with a very low probability, make very large changes to `vx` and `vy` before normalization, making your insect change its path very suddenly at random instances.

Comment: Can you provide an example? My sprites are jittery but generally follow the same path.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `CCBeizierTo`  or `CCBezierBy`
for example:

```
#define randomPoint ccp(CCRANDOM_0_1()*[[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width,CCRANDOM_0_1()*[[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].height)

ccBezierConfig bezier;

bezier.controlPoint_1 = randomPoint;

bezier.controlPoint_2 = randomPoint;

bezier.endPosition = randomPoint;

CCBezierBy* bez = [CCBezierBy actionWithDuration:5.0f bezier:bezier];

[sprite runAction:bez];
```

Comment: The sprite goes off screen :/